# Книга "Сборник рецептов PHP" еще актуальна?

Tags: php, книги

На многих форумах видел сообщения, где советовали **Сборник рецептов PHP (Д. Скляр, А.Х. Трахтенберг) за 2005 и 2007 (второе издание)**, но сообщения были датированы 2005 - 2008 годами.

Актуальна ли она сейчас? И если нет, то есть какая-то достойная альтернатива?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно актуальна, она не только актуальна, а еще и интересно написана! Для справки php 5.х появился в 2004году. Можешь еще почитать эту  "Дэвис М., Филлипс Д. Изучаем PHP и MySQL (2-е издание, 2008)".

Comment: я спрашиваю потому что прочитал PHP для начинающих 2006го года и даже там уже многие фукнции устарели

Comment: Вполне естественное желание не отставать от новинок. Авторы хорошие, книга которую Вам советуют тоже хорошая. Если найдешь более свежую версию этих авторов можешь ликовать и незамедлительно приобретать!