# Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP

Tags: php, книги, faq

Рекомендуемая литература, курсы и документация по PHP.

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте общий ответ.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент, вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: TODO: Материалы [по безопасности](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144134/%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Answer (score 45):

## Официальная документация

- [PHP.NET - Руководство по PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/)

## Литература

#### Для начинающих

- *PHP 7*.  Дмитрий Котеров, Игорь Симдянов.
- *Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5*. Робин Никсон.
- *PHP. Создание динамических страниц*. Дэвид Пауэрс.
- *PHP: Правильный путь*. (*PHP: The right way*) - [Онлайн книга](http://phptherightway.ru/).

#### Для среднего уровня

- *PHP 5. Полное руководство.* Джон Коггзолл
- *PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования*.  Мэт Зандстра.
- *Самоучитель PHP 7*.      Максим Кузнецов, Игорь Симдянов.

#### Для продвинутого уровня

- *[Domain-Driven Design in PHP.](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php)*  Carlos Buenosvinos, Christian Soronellas, Keyvan Akbary

## Полезные ссылки

- [Список всего, связанного с PHP](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php)
- [PhpTheRightWay - список актуальных инструментов/библиотек/подходов](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: Мне бы хотелось ссылки на книги здесь видеть.

Comment: https://github.com/marcelgsantos/learning-oop-in-php

Comment: Обновите Котерова, уже вышла новая книга - Котеров. PHP 7.

Comment: @Jean-Claude ответ общий, отредактируйте его сами, пожалуйста

Comment: На телеграме есть группа `Книги для программистов`. Там есть разные книги по разным языкам программирования