# Записать строку в переменную без вывода

Tags: php

Пример такой:

```
function hello(){
    echo "Hello!";
}

$a = hello();
```

Нужно записать полученную в результате работы функции строку "Hello!" в переменную `$a`, а вместо этого получаю выведенную строку "Hello!" и пустую переменную `$a`. Оператора вывода нет же. Что я не доучил?

Comment: `echo "Hello!";` - это у современных студентов означает "нет оператора вывода?"

Comment: `return 'Hello!'` - так из функции возвращают значения. Есть и экзотические способы, но вам пока и этого хватит

Comment: @Ипатьев  А почему строка в переменную не попадает? Я же не просто делаю вызов функции `hello();` Мне нужно формировать строку с различными условиями  и циклами. Как всё это через `return` вернуть? Например у меня в функции распечатывается массив циклов `foreach`

Comment: @BOPOH как в таком случае использовать `return`?

Comment: @Torawhite, а вы [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php) читали?

Comment: "Что я не доучил?" - Чуть более, чем всё.

Comment: почитайте на досуге что-нибудь из [этого списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458486/5079)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а как тут быть с `return`: `function hello($b){
    if($b == 1){
        echo "<ul>";
        
        foreach($array AS $key => $value){
            echo "<li>$value</li>";
        }        
        
        echo "</ul>";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }

}

$a = hello(1);`

Comment: книжки читайте, зачем вы выводите, если вам достаточно все это в переменной хранить, а потом уже ее и возвращать. Хотя бы "php за 21 день" почитайте - уже представление иметь будете; только потом не забудьте нормальные книжки почитать, а то только хуже сделаете

Comment: @Torawhite, `echo` - оператор вывода, если не надо выводить. не надо его использовать

Answer (score 4):

Все просто. Функция вывода вообще-то есть: [echo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php).

Его аналог - функция [print](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php)

Если вы хотите, чтобы функция что-то возвращала, то ей об этом нужно явно указать:

```
function LearnDocumentation (){
  $eyes = false;     // Оператором "=" присваивается значение переменной
  return "Не хочу!"; // Ключевое слово "return" возвращает значение.
}

$mustLearn = LearnDocumentation();

// А теперь мы можем, если захотим, вывести результат выполнения функции
print $mustLearn;
```

Comment: Спасибо! `LearnDocumentation` и её содержимое повеселило!

Comment: @RostD это-то понятно. А как быть со сложной строкой, которую формирует функция? Выше указал

Comment: @Torawhite, вы разве еще не поняли как работает система? Читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)!

Comment: Понял, примерно - `$b = 1;
function hello($b){
    if($b == 1){
        $array = array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
        foreach($array AS $key => $value){
            $string .= "<li>$value</li>";
        }

        return "<ul>" . $string . "</ul>";
    }else{
        return "Error";
    }

}

$a = hello(1);
echo $a;`

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! Не судите строго!

Answer (score 1):

```
function hello(){
 return "Hello!";
}
```