# Что отвечает за автодобавление контента с высшим рейтингом в рубрику топ недели?

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно сделать `div`, в который будут автоматически добавляться фильмы с высшим рейтингом, как это сделать? Я просто не понимаю, что именно за это отвечает, js? Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно об этом почитать?

[image: что то вроде этого]

Comment: Wordpress написан на языке программирования PHP, по которому на нашем сайте уже есть готовый [список литературы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php). Кроме того, почитайте [документацию](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) по написанию собственных плагинов для Wordpress'а. JavaScript может вам пригодиться, для динамического вывода контента (например, менять

Comment: я написал, что мне бы литературу найти, по этому я и пришел на форум программистов, что бы конкретно и по делу читать, а не кучу бессмысленных постов в интернете, помощи в программировании я не жду..вы видимо просто не правильно прочитали мой вопрос или не дочитали. За документацию спасибо большое.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь вам надо понять логику как это работает. 
Опишу как действовал бы я.

1. Определил есть ли необходимость хранить хранить в базе данных отметки. Поскольку при выключении браузера пользователя эти данные должны сохранятся то значит данные должны храниться в базе данных. Соответственно уже используется PHP.
2. Как создать базу данных тут гугл в помощь мне вот что [выдало](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) плагины для создания сразу отбросим вот годная [статья](http://mblogm.ru/blog/wordpress-plugin-data-base-1/) и вот тоже [нормальная](https://wpmag.ru/2014/custom-tables-dbdelta/) извените но свой путь выбирать надо самому я не подсказчик тут. В конце можно просто через phpmyadmin.
3. База по моему мнению должна содержать содержать id, id_post, rating, . Записывать туда можно через ajax по клику записывать или через форму с чекбоксом. Опять же выбор за вами.
4. Дальше через класс wpdb получать данные из таблицы и уже через javascript вычислять рейтинг исходя из общей суммы рейтинга деленной на количество записей (по id_post). получил id_post нужных мне постов и дальше  через get_posts вывел нужные посты

а можно если нет желания заморачиваться использовать этот [плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) ну или подобные им но это скучно и не программно.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать.

Comment: не забудьте принять ответ если помог. Это вам на этом портале очень поможет в будущем :). Ели будете здесь работать .