# Не работает код PHP, ничего не выводит

Tags: php

Не работает PHP.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
$c = "6";
if ($a == $b) or ($c == $b) echo "hello";
```

В чём ошибка?

Comment: Не работает PHP.

<?php

$a = 5;
$b = 6;
$c = "6";
if ($a == $b) or ($c == $b) echo "hello";

?>

В чём ошибка?

Comment: Я ввожу текст с кодом, использую старый моб. браузер. Текст выводит, а PHP - нет. Хотя, нажимаю "править", и всё показывает.

Comment: Я отредактировал.

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера было то же самое, но через некоторое время вывело код.

Comment: Потому что надо `if ($a == $b or $c == $b)`. Убедительно прошу - выучите для начала основы языка программирования.

Comment: Так в чём же ошибка? Заранее, благодарен.

Comment: Спасибо, интернет опоздал

Comment: Спасибо. Я копирую с самоучителя, вот в чём дело. А там так, как в вопросе. Поэтому и спрашиваю, потому что странно.

Comment: @Max сожгите этот самоучитель ..... попробуйте посмотреть что-то отсюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php

Comment: @Max ....... можно ссылку на что за самоучитель и на какой странице это находится? интересно

Comment: Прошу минутку...

Comment: Извините, решил не давать ссылку. Друг, который посоветовал изучать PHP, создал небольшой сайт для чайников. Посоветую ему самому воспользоваться Вашей ссылкой на материалы.

Благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Можно совсем ничего не менять и просто добавить внешние скобки: `if(($a == $b) or ($c == $b)) echo "hello";`. Хотя вариант, который предложил @isnullxbh самый элегантный.

Comment: Спасибо. Хочу взяться за "Робин Никсон. Создаём динамические веб сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript и CSS. Второе издание" Стоит?

Comment: Стоит познакомить нас с Вашим другом ) Он сам знает, что у него есть сайт для чайников ?))

Comment: Смешно. После этого случая друзьями нас вряд ли можно назвать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

```
if ($a == $b || $c == $b) echo "hello";
```