# Стоит ли изучать сейчас PHP?

Tags: php

Стоит ли изучать сейчас слоника?) Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего начать обучение PHP. Дайте пожалуйста конструктивный и серьезный ответ. Спасибо)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Comment: вот вам книги и ресурсы - учите

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно стоит!
Самые ярые нелюбители php работали с 4 версией
Следующие нелюбители с версией до 5.4
Сейчас php7 и он прекрасен, у нелюбителей php даже аргументы заканчиваются.
Работы на php море

1. Пройдите любые онлайн уроки и читайте документацию по php - Это даст вам основу и понимание.
2. Затем возьмите фреймворк Laravel (он проще остальных
   других и документация простая) и напишите блог с комментариями и авторизацией
3. Теперь попробуйте написать блог с комментариями и авторизацией на своём велосипеде.

Везде советуют сначала шаг 3, потом 2. Но я советую вам, в том порядке, котором я написал. Это даст вам понимание как строятся приложения на php.
А потом, когда вы напишите на своём велосипеде, то у вас будет понимание как велосипед собирать.

И ещё, раньше во всех учебниках писали PHP + MySQL. Но вместо MySQL я советую вам использовать PostgreSQL

**P.S.** Войну `Laravel vs Yii` и `PostgreSQL vs MySQL` можно не объявлять

Comment: нелюбители php всегда есть и будут как религиозные люди:  бог есть, кто не верит - должен быть сожжен...... Этого не изменить даже с php 100 =)

Comment: Дизайн языка - ущербен. Одни неконсистентные имена функций и перемешенный порядок аргументов у функциональных обработчиков массивов чего стоят... И PHP7 не меняет ситуацию. Вообще.

Comment: Хотел бы я взглянуть на _неущербный дизайн языка_)

Answer (score 1):

Да, стоит. Не особо его любят, слишком уж много он вызывает противоречий, но порог вхождения очень низкий. Проектов на нем написано много и востребован он будет ещё долгое время. Любая книга, рассматривающая PHP 5.4 и выше подойдет, в основном там один и тот же материал. Чтобы разобраться, стоит написать проект с нуля.