# Дайте рекомендация при работе на высоких нагрузках

Tags: php

Пожалуйста дайте материалы, статьи, учебники, советы по работе сайта на php с высокими нагрузками

Comment: php c высокими нагрузками? Мне кажется тут проще нормальный сервер арендовать, чем пытаться выйграть что-то на php.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 1):

Начните с изучения http://ruhighload.com/ 
Там поднимается много тем, связанных с оптимизацией и масштабированием Web приложений.