# Создание профиля для каждого пользователя

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Для каждого пользователя нужно создавать отдельный файл (типа *profile1.php*, *profile2.php* и т.д.)?
Чтобы другой зарегистрированный пользователь мог просматривать его профиль.

Comment: нет не нужно создавать отдельный файл для каждого.................... Я вижу не первый ваш вопрос  и они на столько низкокачественные,  видно что вы мало что читали об этих ЯП....... и решаются банально прочиткой книг по PHP и MySQL. Или просмотром видеокурса по PHP например от [Специалист] ....... мне кажется вам стоит начать с них

Comment: Вариант создания таблицы `UserProfiles` в БД и хранения информации там выглядит, на мой взгляд, гораздо лучше.

Comment: взгляните на этот раздел на досуге: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/)

Comment: Да я недавно начал читать про пэхэпэ, но курсач горит( надо как-то по быстрому сдать вот я и задаю вопросы торопясь и "низкокачественным". Извиняюсь! и спс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что Вы, нет, конечно. PHP это как раз тот язык в котором такого рода действия предотвращаются. Это сделать можно в одном файле, но прежде определитесь с уровнями доступа типа пользователь/модератор/администратор.

При регистрации например устанавливайте по умолчанию пользовательский уровень и направляйте всех с уровнем "пользователь" на файл например "level_user.php", а администраторов на "level_admin.php", в один файл тоже не следует все распихивать по хорошему, а то запутаетесь в условиях "if/else"

А вообще ознакомьтесь с ООП стилем PHP (объектно-ориентированное программирование) и MVC  (Model-View-Controller: модель-вид-контроллер).

А определение пользователя по id можно устанавливать через $_GET, например в ссылке "/profile_user.php&user_id=65464654" "user_id" 'ключ по которому можно получить id пользователя вот таким образом:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```

и не забывайте обрабатывать все что приходит через глобальные массивы $_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE, цифры например id приводите к целому числу тем же (int) и что-бы там не прийдет либо это будет целая цифра либо нуль.

```
$user_id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
```

собственно наша переменная "$user_id" теперь имеет id с которым мы обращаемся в базу данных.

Если я Вас верно понял конечно.