# Посоветуйте источники для изучения PHP

Tags: php

На протяжении месяца изучал HTML + CSS, сверстал 5  PSD-шаблонов...
И хотелось бы идти дальше, то есть к PHP. Какие посоветуете видео-уроки, ну или же книги)

Comment: php.net вот и весь источник , php.su тоже не плохой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ресурсы:

- [Udemy.com](http://Udemy.com)
- [YouTube.com](http://YouTube.com)
- [Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/)
- StackOverflow (Если правильно в гугле или тут задать запрос на интересующий вопрос - запросто найдешь ответ)

Книги:

- Head First PHP & MySQL

Телеграм-канал с книгами:

- [Бздынь.Канал](https://t.me/bzd_channel)
- [Книги для программистов](https://t.me/progbook)

Answer (score 0):

Сборник самых лучших ресурсовой по изучению `PHP`, и на другие сайты ходить не надо. :)

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php)