# ajax отправляет запрос в один php скрипт, как получить ответ с другого php скрипта

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

у меня есть js скрипт который отправляет запрос на сервер методом ajax, как я понял ответить js скрипту должен тот же php скрипт который и принял запрос, вопрос ест ли способ сделать так чтобы ответ пришёл с другого скрипта, скажем запрос принял act_input.php но ответит должен act_output.php, питаюсь реализовать патерн mvs и там "контроллер" принимает запрос (в том числе ajax) но ответ должен же вернуть "вид", подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Comment: не mvs, а mvc. И я тебя удивлю, но ответ вернёт контроллер. вот только ответ может быть разный: может быть просто json, а может html. Откуда он возьмёт данные - его дело. Он может заинклудить шаблон "вида" и его выплюнуть как ответ

Comment: А для того, чтобы вот тысяча таких вопросов не возникало - для начала прочитай книги по PHP. Есть наверняка книги, которые уже с самого нуля до ООП+MVC всё разбирали детально и не раз

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458486/191482)