# Не происходит вычисления

Tags: php

Вот обычный, простой код PHP:

```
$a = file("users/$filename/text.txt");

$b = 30;

$summ = $a + $b;

$file = fopen("users/$filename/text.txt", 'w');

fwrite($file, $summ);

fclose($file);
```

Задача:
Вынести содержимое файла text.txt (там только число, например: 30) в переменную a и прибавить к ней вторую переменную b, ну и потом занести всё обратно с перезаписью.

Всё бы ничего, только вот он в переменную a из файла вбивает 30 ни как число, а как текст что-ли. Получается, что он будто считает его нулём . В общем видимо он видит переменную b как строку текста, а ни как число с которым можно производить вычисления. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как заставить его применить выражения с числом из файла. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо.

Comment: что прописано в файле?

Comment: в доки смотрели? "`file` - Возвращает файл **в виде массива.**"

Comment: В файле прописано 30

Comment: Ну а как тогда извлечь его в виде числа, или может как-то преобразовать?

Comment: ну ты подумай, как можно взять данные из массива?

Comment: Может поэтому я и задаю здесь вопрос потому что уже все книги прошелестил, а в инете подобных вопрос вообще нет.

Comment: То есть ни одной книги в которых описано работа с массивами? Правда?

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458486/191482)    начните с "PHP 7. Дмитрий Котеров"

Comment: ты точно прошерстил все доки? на страничке https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file внизу есть подраздел "Смотрите также". Ты там вообще был?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в строке 3 использовать вместо $a запись $a[0] если число в файле записано строкой. Функция file() отдаёт массив строк файла.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Больше подробностей это сколько?