# Зачем нужны namespace в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Зачем в каждом файле нужно прописывать `namespace` при использовании фреймворка `Yii2`?

```php
namespace app\controllers;
```

Comment: ровно для того, как и в других проектах нужны неймспейсы. yii2 тут совершенно не причём. Изучайте  ООП дальше. дойдёте и до этой темы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Неймспейс** (`namespace`) — это внутренний (для интерпретатора PHP) путь к файлу во фреймворке. Обычно он соответствует иерархии директорий, чтобы было более понятно человеку. Однако может и не соответствокать, это зависит от того, как сконфигурирован автозагрузчик файлов в PHP.

При формировании неймспейсов рекомендуется использовать стандарт [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).