# Формa отправки сообщения

Tags: php, html, sendmessage

Как подключить «Форму отправки сообщения» в html-файле к php, чтобы все сообщения, введенные в данной форме на веб-сайте, отправлялись прямо на мой адрес Gmail?

```
 <section id="contact">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                     <form id="contact-form" role="form" action="action.php" method="post">
                          <div class="section-title">
                               <h2>Contact us <small>We are open to talk. We work for you. Let us talk!</small></h2>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                               <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name" name="text" required="">
                
                               <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" name="email" required="">

                               <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Tell us about your message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                               <input type="submit" id="submit" class="form-control" name="send message" value="Send Message">
                          </div>

                     </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                     <div class="contact-image">
                          <img src="images/kingdom.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kingdom Education Logo">
                     </div>
                </div>

           </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Прочтите хотя бы одну книгу по PHP

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки собщения на почту в PHP есть функция mail().
Гугл в помощь.

```
<?php
// Сообщение
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// На случай если какая-то строка письма длиннее 70 символов мы используем wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Отправляем
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```