# Как получить id из базы данных в php файл как переменную?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Всем привет я новичек на php и я уже долго не могу поянть как получить id из базы данных в переменную для проверок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Comment: Я иногда объясняю новичкам, как работать с бд и написал небольшую [заметку про mysqli](https://egorbanin.github.io/fs/mysqli/). Почитайте, возможно вам будет полезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно суть вопроса, но все же постараюсь ответить. Это как пример.
Нужно с помощью SQL запроса `"SELECT * FROM` actor`WHERE`name `= 'Иван'"` получить все данные где имя Иван. Полученные результат поместить в массив. Пример:

```
$array = [
"ID" => "36",
"name" => "Иван",
"age" => "27",
"city" => "Kyiv"];
```

Тогда $array[ID] - это и будет значение только ID.
$a = $array[ID], в переменной $a будет просто 36

Comment: Всё работает правильно, но как я могу сделать чтоб вместо ('Иван') была переменная?

Comment: @sanja_groznij Вам необходимо узнать id определенной строки. У Вас же есть критерий какой то определенной строки (по которой ее можно узнать), например в той строке есть имя, возраст, еще что то. Вот вам и нужно в PHP создать функцию с SQL запросом который будет вытягивать всю ту строку и запишет ее в массив. А далее как я указал ранее