# PHP Как вывести данные из столбца в таблице mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно вывести из таблицы users значение столбца domain, при этом они должны принадлежать только тому пользователю кто вошёл в аккаунт. Не понимаю как это сделать, предложите пожалуйста свои варианты кода

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Comment: Покажите ваше подключение к базе данных

Comment: Уже всё решено.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужен некий ключ, по которому будете производить условие запроса. Давайте набросаем пример

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' ");
```

Так будет выглядеть срока запрока к БД. Но прошу вас обратить внимание, что я подключился к БД через PDO. Ну и кончно же в самом запросе у меня присутствует ключ апо которому я делаю обращение.

Вам в свою очередь этот ключь нужно будет определить, к примеру если ваш пользователь авторизван на сайте при помощи Куки `$_COOKIE['username'];` то, перед самим запросом в переменную $username положите эту куку.

После этого совершите сам запрос, например через цикл

`foreach($query as $user);`

После таких манипуляций уже можете обращаться к переменной $user и ее данным. Для мониторинга того, что лежит в этой переменной вопользуйтесь встроенной ункцией

`var_dump($user);`

В резултате должен у вас получиться от такой код:

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' ");
foreach($query as $user);
var_dump($user['domain'];
```

Удачи! задавайте вопросы

Comment: Примерно вот так?  $username = $_SESSION['login'];

Comment: Приерно! Пробуйте, но старайтесь не нарушать указанную мною конструкцию использую все виды кавычек)

Comment: $login = $_SESSION['login'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
foreach($query as $login);
var_dump($login);
Я сделал вот так это работает но с именем пользователя как мне сделать с именем домена не совсем понятно

Comment: $login['domain']; НЕ забудьте мой ответ (над нашими комментраиями) отметить как принятый)

Comment: Сделал так как вы сказали и выводится NULL $login['domain'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
foreach($query as $login);
var_dump($login);

Comment: та неееееет!! Вы перед тем как сделать запрос передавать должны. логин в тело запроса. Верните как было, а после того как циклом совершите сам запрос, выведите $login['domain']

Comment: $login = $_SESSION['login'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
foreach($query as $login);
$login['domain'];
var_dump($login); сделал так но выводится логин юзера

Comment: Вы издеваетесь?))) в var_dump() выведете не просто $login, а $login['domain'];

Comment: выводится тогда первая буква логина

Comment: Если вы не из РФ, то напишите мне в телеграм @four_kilograms продолжим беседу там

Answer (score 0):

```
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `domain` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'", $db);
foreach($query as $login);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $myrow['domain'];
```

Спасибо 4 kilograms за ответ ниже работает с таким кодом