# Как получить значение ключа в массиве json PHP

Tags: php, json

Делаю api запрос к серверу, он мне возвращает ответ в json-формате.
Ответ читает и выводится echo на экран, но мне необходимо получить только одно значение одного ключа в массиве - phone.

Приведу пример json:

```
[{ "status": 23, "last_date": "20.07.2023 09:59:16", "last_timestamp": 1689839956, "flag": 0, "err": 252, "send_date": "20.07.2023 09:59:16", "send_timestamp": 1689839956, "phone": "тут номер телефона будет", "cost": "0.00", "sender_id": "test", "status_name": "���������", "message": "тестовое сообщение", "country": "������", "operator": "������", "operator_orig": "���", "region": "������������� �������", "type": 0 }]
```

Т.е нужно просто вывести на экран не массив, а значение "phone".

Пробовал сделать, как советовали в комментариях:

```
$response = '[{ "status": 23, "last_date": "20.07.2023 09:59:16", "phone": 777}]';

$response = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response[0]['phone'];
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\sms.php on line 11

Вот весь код:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://smsc.ru/sys/get.php?get_messages=1&login=alex&psw=123&cnt=1&fmt=3');

$response = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response[0]['phone'];
```

Ответ возвращается в формате string от сервера

Comment: Делаете `json_decode()` того что Вам приходит и потом обращаетесь через `$response[0]->phone`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Comment: $response[0]->phone
Не помогает, тоже пишет, что value of type null

Comment: Не знаю что Вы там пробовали, но это рабочий код [https://onlinephp.io/c/7e5da](https://onlinephp.io/c/7e5da)

Comment: json-ответ от сервера должен быть string или array? через var_dump пишет, что json - это string

Comment: @VIKTORPETR string, для преобразования из строки и используется json_decode()

Comment: NULL выводит, если через json_decode() делать

Answer (score 1):

**Используйте json_decode() чтобы декодировать строку JSON и [0] чтобы получить данные с первого элемента массива**

```
$response = '[{ "status": 23, "last_date": "20.07.2023 09:59:16", "phone": 777}]';

$response = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response[0]['phone'];
```

Comment: В массиве объект.

Comment: @Simon спасибо)

Comment: да, через foreach или любой другой цикл. Но! Эти ответы не для того чтобы задавать новые вопросы или чатиться. Новый вопрос задавайте как новый вопрос!