# Не могу подключиться к базам данных

Tags: php, mysql

Я новичок в php, но очень хочу обучится. Создала обычную форму, но не могу подключиться к базам данных. При нажатии на кнопку, происходит подключение к файлу php, но в браузере ничего не отображается. Не могу найти ошибку.

файлы:
index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width? initial- scale-1.0">
    
<title>CSS</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
    
<body>
        
<header>
        <section>
            <form action="/php/register.php" method="post">
              <label for="login">Логин</label><br>
                <input type="txt" name="login" id="login"><br><br>
              <label for="password">Пароль</label><br>
              <input type="txt" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
              <label for="email">E-mail</label><br>
            <input type="txt" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
              <button class="button-a">Зарегистрироваться</button>
            </form>
        </section>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

register.php:

```php
<?php
 
| require_once('db.php');
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
  
?>
```

db.php:

```hphp
<?php
 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$bdname = "users";
 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $bdname);
 
if (!$conn){
    due("Сonnection file". myesquel_connect_error());
 }   elso {
        echo "Успех";
    }
?>
```

может быть что то необходимо подключить, потому что делаю с 0.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что подключентя нет? Почему вы решили, что форма отправляется? Почему должно что то отобразится в браузере?

Comment: Вы что, сканировали код с бумажного листа? Что такое "due", "myesquel"?

Comment: Потому что `<button class="button-a">Зарегистрироваться</button>` у вас ничего не делает. Вместо этого поставьте: `<input type="submit" class="button-a" value="Зарегистрироваться">`

Comment: @SemyonBayandin удали свой комментарий, не позорься.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Тут целая россыпь ошибок. Как минимум то, что указал void. И ещё минимум парочка. Их можно увидеть включив вывод ошибок в PHP (см дубликат выше). А также худо бедно как-нибудь прочитав документацию по тем конструкциям и функциям, которые используются в коде

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и что же именно в нём позорного? У человека не отправляется форма. Я ответил на вопрос почему. Про всё остальное вопросов не было. Вопросы?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin позорно то, что ты не знаешь азы. И пытаешься втюхать старообрядческие подходы, не смотря на то, что и текущая реализация вполне себе рабочая........И всё вполне себе отправляется, просто проблемы на сервере.

Comment: SwaD: "должно отображаться слово "Успех", при вводе данных. Его нет, пустой лист

Comment: Алексей Шиманский: что лучше почитать, чтобы понять как грамотнее писать коды? А то я с видео на ютубе учусь.

Comment: @AliciaBrooks читай книги по PHP (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458485/191482   ...  хотя бы PHP 7. Дмитрий Котеров, Игорь Симдянов)   .... для текущего вопроса я указал ссылку выше для прочтения (читай все ответы)......А с ютуба ты как-то сильно невнимательно списываешь, потому что таких слов в языке программирования не существует ...... если только у тебя не дислексия.....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Москва тоже не с первого дня строилась. А оскорблять человека (если только у тебя не дислексия) только потому что он чего то не знает, не делает из вас джентльмена, помогающего новичку, а наоборот опускает до уровня среднестатистического быдла...спасибо за книги, я учту, что почтить, чтобы избавится от своей "дислексии".

Comment: @AliciaBrooks если человек нашёл оскорбления там, где их не было, то, возможно, у такого человека и правда с головой что-то...не дислексия, но что-то другое...

Answer (score -3):

У вас ошибка в коде:

```
due("Сonnection file". myesquel_connect_error());
```

правильно функция будет die(), также есть ее эквивалент exit().

```
die("Сonnection file". myesquel_connect_error());
```

И кнопке требуется добавить type="submit":

```
<button class="button-a" type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
```

то бы отправлялась форма.

И наконец, что бы узнать есть подключение к базе данных сделайте

```
var_dump($conn);
```

и посмотрите, что у вас в переменной.

Что бы PHP выводил Вам все ошибки, добавьте вначале PHP файла:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: *"И кнопке требуется добавить type="submit":"* --- нет **не требуется**

Comment: А функция `myesquel_connect_error` тоже существует?

Comment: Не нужно пытаться отвечать, если вы не разбираетесь в вопросе, и не можете дать всеобъемлющий ответ. То, что вы написали - это разрозненные комментарии к отдельным кускам вопроса, а не ответ на вопрос "как соединяться с БД". И писать их надо в комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: не особо поняла к какой переменной мне стоит вставить var_dump. и какому конкретно php файлу добавить error_reporting(E_ALL)?

Comment: В файл db.php добавьте первой строчкой error_reporting(E_ALL), а после строчки $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $bdname); выведете var_dump($conn); что бы увидеть, что у Вас в переменной $conn

Comment: Спасибо большое, добавила и тоже самое выводится - белый экран

Comment: Белый экран не может выводиться, если PHP работает, как у вас в коде есть ошибки

Comment: @aletoropov белый экран **МОЖЕТ** выводиться, если в PHP ошибки. Не вводи в заблуждение людей